# C# XML - Reading Included XML Document

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

I have created a basic project in to which i have added a really simple xml file. I can see the file and my one form in the project solution. I am trying to write code to read the xml file but i cant seem to access it as visual studio doesnt seem to be picking up that its there if that makes sense? How do i get at that file so i can do something like

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("My document here")
```

Thanks

Comment: You can make it as embedded resource or use copy always

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean you added the xml-file to the solution? If so, you need to edit the properties of the xml-file (right click in solution-explorer and select properties), and set it to always copy on build. This will copy the xml-file to the bin/Debug-folder when you build, and this is where the program is run from. If not you need to change the file-path to "../../filename.xml", this will also work.

**Note**:
This is only a solution to your problem if the xml-file is part of the solution, and the program doesn't find the file when you run it. And you must not be using absolute paths.

Comment: yes i added the xml file to my solution. I have now right clicked properties on the xml file and set copy to output directory to always. However intellisense still doesnt pick up the file name unless it shouldnt?

Comment: It won't pick up the file name, you'll still have to reference it as a string, but now you can reference it without providing any path (as it will always be in the same path as the output executable)

Comment: Also, one more thing, for simplicity I recommend using LINQ to XML to parse XML-files. It's (subjectively seeking of cause) the simplest way to read xml-files.

Answer (score 3):

Add the xml file as a resource to your project (build action = embedded resource). And use:

```
    public static XmlDocument GetEmbeddedXml(Assembly assembly, string fileName)
    {
        using (var str = GetEmbeddedFile(assembly, fileName))
        {
            using (var tr = new XmlTextReader(str))
            {
                var xml = new XmlDocument();
                xml.Load(tr);
                return xml;
            }
        }
    }

    public static Stream GetEmbeddedFile(Assembly assembly, string fileName)
    {
        string assemblyName = assembly.GetName().Name;
        Assembly a = Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
        Stream str = a.GetManifestResourceStream(assemblyName + "." + fileName);

        if (str == null)
            throw new Exception("Could not locate embedded resource '" + fileName + "' in assembly '" + assemblyName + "'");
        return str;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something along the lines of:

```
using(XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader ("yourfile.xml"))
{

    while (reader.Read()) 
    {
        switch (reader.NodeType) 
        {
            case XmlNodeType.Element: // The node is an element.
                Console.Write("<" + reader.Name);
                Console.WriteLine(">");
                break;
            case XmlNodeType.Text: //Display the text in each element.
                Console.WriteLine (reader.Value);
                break;
            case XmlNodeType. EndElement: //Display the end of the element.
                Console.Write("</" + reader.Name);
                Console.WriteLine(">");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I assume you want to parse the XML file after you have read it in?